# Why do the keras loss functions reduce the dimensionality by one?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

When computing the loss between y_true and y_pred, the keras loss functions reduce the dimensionality by one. For example, when training a network on pairs of 64x64 greyscale images with batch size = 8, the shape of y_true and y_pred would be (8, 64, 64). The keras loss functions will produce a loss tensor with shape (8, 64), averaging over the last dimension.
I do not get why that would be necessary, all it does is average the loss over the rows of the image. Doesn't the network need the loss to be calculated individually for every output value (and therefore conserve the shape)? As far as I understand it, backpropagation looks at the individual loss of each output value compared to the target, and then updates previous weights accordingly. How can it do that, just knowing the averaged loss of each row, not every value individually? Here is a code snippet that shows the behaviour I described:

```
y_true = K.random_uniform([8,64,64])
y_pred = K.random_uniform([8,64,64])
c= mean_absolute_error(y_true,y_pred)
print(K.eval(tf.shape(c)))  # (8,64)
```

Comment: last dimension is used to compute the loss itself. In your case for elements corresponding to the last dimension, `mean_absolute_error` is calculated

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that, I am still a beginner at machine learning, so the explanation is probably obvious. What do you mean by "elements corresponding to the last dimension"? Why would those elements be treated differently than elements corresponding to the second-to-last dimension, even though they are pretty much interchangeable?

Comment: as an example, say you have a vector of dimension, say `(10, 5, 2)` and you want to sum it up. Now generally the library would ask you which axis, but let's say by default it takes the last axis. Then in the 3d matrix, items are summed along the third dimension and the resulting matrix is only 2d dimensional. Summing again you get a column vector of length 10. Hope this example is clear

Comment: That makes sense, but I still don't get why that is necessary. It sums up the losses in the last dimension, which represents the coloums of the image. Why would it need to sum that up? Doesn't it need the specific loss for every output value?

Comment: consider two column vectors. To compute mean_absolute_error, you need to sum the absolute differences between the vectors and then divide by the number of elements in each vector. What you get as a result is just a number, that is you have gone from 1d to 0d. This summing operation in the loss function results in decrease of dimension. Please let me know if this makes sense in you case

Answer (score 2):

I wondered the same thing. I believe, Keras assumes your data to have the following dimensions: [batch, W, H, n_classes] which means averaging over axis=-1 means averaging the loss over all different classes. However, in your case you do not have that dimension because you presumably do a binary classification in a grayscale image. So instead it ends up averaging the loss over the rows/columns. Interestingly enough, the model can still train and even improve in performance like this, which makes me believe that people in similar situations often just train their model without ever noticing.

You can avoid this by adding a dummy axis to your data.

This is how I got there:

From: https://keras.io/api/losses/

"(Note ondN-1: all loss functions reduce by 1 dimension, usually axis=-1.) “
Furthermore:  "loss class instances feature a reduction constructor argument, which defaults to "sum_over_batch_size" (i.e. average). Allowable values are "sum_over_batch_size", "sum", and "none":
• "sum_over_batch_size" means the loss instance will return the average of the per-sample losses in the batch.
• "sum" means the loss instance will return the sum of the per-sample losses in the batch.
• "none" means the loss instance will return the full array of per-sample losses. "

From https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/Reduction

"Caution: Verify the shape of the outputs when using Reduction.NONE. The builtin loss functions wrapped by the loss classes reduce one dimension (axis=-1, or axis if specified by loss function). Reduction.NONE just means that no additional reduction is applied by the class wrapper. For categorical losses with an example input shape of [batch, W, H, n_classes] the n_classes dimension is reduced. For pointwise losses you must include a dummy axis so that [batch, W, H, 1] is reduced to [batch, W, H]. Without the dummy axis [batch, W, H] will be incorrectly reduced to [batch, W]."